# Hide method signatures in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to document some Java REST interfaces uses Doxygen, [similar to this](http://status.net/docs/api/publictimeline.html).

The problem I'm having is that I can't remove the method signature from the output, so each section looks like this:

---

```
Book com.place.getBook(@QueryParam("title") String title, @QueryParam("author"))
```

This method returns a book or list of books matching the given title and author.

**Parameters:**

- title - The title of the book
- author - The author(s) of the book. Separate multiple authors with commas.

---

But what I actually want is to display the URL and no method signature:

---

**URL:** `/services/book?title={title}&author={author}`

This method returns a book or list of books matching the given title and author.

**Parameters:**

- title - The title of the book
- author - The author(s) of the book. Separate multiple authors with commas.

---

I think I can add my URL tag using a custom alias, but how do I get rid of the method signature?